# Thread executes once more after it has been ended

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, socketexception

This involves server-client networking via socket. Client thread is running on `while(boolean)` loop. It is accessed from ClientBean class and the condition is set false. this should stop the thread or terminate it. But I see the thread attempts to read InputStream of socket once more after I set the thread's run's loop's condition false. This throws a **SocketException**.

The bean's code part:-

```
public void disconnect() {
        client.setSendMessage(key + "disconnect");
        thd.setRunning(false);
        client.setRunning(false);
        try {
            client.getSock().close();
            inputDisabled = sendBtnDisabled = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the thread's run() method :-

```
public void run() {
        while (running) {

            try {
                if (!sock.isClosed())
                    if ((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) {
                        msg = receiveMessage;
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I get exception on the line `if ((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null)`.
Why does the loop of run() execute once more after thread is stopped? And moreover how does it satisfy the condition `if (!sock.isClosed())` when I have closed the socket from bean?

Comment: Is `running` volatile? Maybe the thread still sees it as `true`.

Comment: You need to provide more code, pertaining to the threads and the socket; also the complete stack trace.

Comment: No, it is  not volatile.

Comment: As far as functionality is concerned, it works fine, everything. Only thing is this one exception in console everytime a user disconnects

Comment: As i know when the connection is closed, -1 is sent.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the loop of run() execute once more after thread is stopped?

Your loop states

```
while (running) {
```

so it loops until `running = false`  note, when you do

```
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // print error and pretend it didn't happen.
        }
```

The simple solution is to put the try/catch outside the loop so that when an error occurs it breaks the loop, or you could close the connection and try again

> how does it satisfy the condition if (!sock.isClosed()) when I have closed the socket from bean?

This method will return isClosed == true once you have called close() on the socket.

Comment: But I want a smooth process where my code does not attempt to read from streams whose socket has been closed. logically that's what I tried to do: stop the thread and then close the socket

Comment: @SohamBanerjee most of the time, your thread will blocking on the readLine() so it is too late to check the socket. What I do is set a field `boolean closed` to `true` just before closing the socket.  If I get an IOException I ignore the exception if it occurred after I tried to close the socket.